# Modeling Java Iterables: Route impl Iterable<Stations> or route.stations()?

Tags: java, collections, iterator, domain-driven-design

There are `Route` and `Station` classes in my domain. Route describes a journey taken by a vehicle through sequence Stations and journey metadata (operator, bus no etc).

Therefore, Route will have a List of Stations and some additional metadata. There is also a necessity in some helper methods for this list, for example, firstStation() and lastStation() and here I have 2 options:

---

***Implement them in Route class:***

```
public class Route implements Iterable<Station> {

    // metadata

    private List<Station> stations;

    public Station firstStation() {
        return stations.get(0);
    }

    public Station lastStation() {
        return stations.get(stations.size() - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Station> iterator() {
        return stations.iterator();
    }


    // ...
}
```

The only thing that worries me is that **Route** provides **Station** iterator it may not be very obvious to developer, especially in this case:

```
for (Station st : route)
```

but it looks natural for first/last methods:

```
Station st = route.firstStation();
```

---

*Another idea is to **create custom collection implementation:***

```
public class Stations implements Iterable<Station> {
    private List<Station> stations;

    public Stations(List<Station> stations) {
        this.stations = stations;
    }

    public Station lastStation() {
        return stations.get(stations.size() - 1);
    }

    public Station firstStation() {
        return stations.get(0);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Station> iterator() {
        return stations.iterator();
    }
}

public class Routte {
    private Iterable<Station> stations = new Stations();

    public Iterable<Station> stations() {
        return stations;
    }
}
```

So this code is more meaningful:

```
for (Station st : route.stations())
```

This approach is more verbose and requires some tricks in order to create JPA mapping.

This question is about you personal preferences and I'll be happy to hear your suggestions and thoughts about how the above code should be implemented in your opinion (and why).

Comment: I'd say: choose composition over inheritance whenever possible. I think in that case code is far better readble...

Comment: Or you could use a LinkedList for your Stations and use the built in getFirst() and getLast() methods.

Comment: @ppeterka so your vote is for 1th approach, isn't it?

Comment: No. Don't implement Iterable. In fact, don't implement anything: there is a nice collection of Collections in Java by default... Do as @Nicktar advised: use a LinkedList. No need to invent another wheel.

Comment: I don't understand why you need a separate class. Why don't you simply return the stations? Apart from this, I agree, `for (Station st : route)` looks weird.

Comment: @ppeterka first/last methods are just examples :)

Comment: @Guenther because i need to add my custom methods for this collection somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your custom methods seem to operate on the "Route" I would go for

```
public class Route {
    private List<Station> stations;

    public Station firstStation() {
        return stations.get(0);
    }

    public Station lastStation() {
        return stations.get(stations.size() - 1);
    }

    public Iterable<Station> getStations() {
        return stations;
    }

    private static class Station {

    }
}
```

This allows you to add custom methods to Route and still have

```
for (Station st : route.getStations())
```

Comment: Upvoted because of the nice design. Just a detail, it doesn’t make sense to have `Station` be a private inner class and return `Iterable<Station>`.

Comment: @Ole V.V.  I only created Station as an inner class to have a minmal self contained example that compiles.